# pyspark dataframe map object attribute to schema column name

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark

I have a list of objects and I want to create a dataframe with a schema. How do I map the object attribute name to schema column names.. Following is what my class looks like

```py
@dataclass
class UberLog(object):
  upi: int
  event_name: str
  event_date: datetime
  source: str
  page_url: str = ""
  event_string: str = ""
  event_details: dict = field(default_factory=dict)
  _event_time: int = field(init=False)
  _id:str = field(init=False)
```

Following is my schema that I want to map to

```py
UBER_LOG_SCHEMA: Final[StructType] = StructType([
    StructField('id', StringType(), False),
    StructField('upi', IntegerType(), False),
    StructField('eventName', StringType(), True),
    StructField('eventDate', TimestampType(), False),
    StructField('eventEpoch', LongType(), False),
    StructField('source', StringType(), False),
    StructField('pageUrl', StringType(), True),
    StructField('eventString', StringType(), True),
    StructField('eventDetails', MapType(StringType(), StringType()), True)
  ])
```

When do the following

```py
 df = spark.createDataFrame(logs, schema=UBER_LOG_SCHEMA)
 df.show()
```

I get the following error `ValueError: field id: This field is not nullable, but got None`

How do I tell in the dataframe creation the mapping for eg: `_id` maps to `id` etc.. ? or is there any other way I can map the column names ?

***************** Updated ****************

The only way I am able to covert my data class to match schema is by column renaming. I was wondering if there is a better solution than this ?

```py
  df = spark.createDataFrame(logs)

  df = df.select(df['*']) \
    .withColumnRenamed("_id", "id") \
    .withColumnRenamed("event_name", "eventName") \
    .withColumnRenamed("event_date", "eventDate") \
    .withColumnRenamed("_event_time", "eventEpoch") \
    .withColumnRenamed("page_url", "pageUrl") \
    .withColumnRenamed("event_string", "eventString") \
    .withColumnRenamed("event_details", "eventDetails")

  df.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way I am able to covert my data class to match schema is by column renaming. I was wondering if there is a better solution than this ?

```py
  df = spark.createDataFrame(logs)

  df = df.select(df['*']) \
    .withColumnRenamed("_id", "id") \
    .withColumnRenamed("event_name", "eventName") \
    .withColumnRenamed("event_date", "eventDate") \
    .withColumnRenamed("_event_time", "eventEpoch") \
    .withColumnRenamed("page_url", "pageUrl") \
    .withColumnRenamed("event_string", "eventString") \
    .withColumnRenamed("event_details", "eventDetails")

  df.show()
```